# CAF receiver customization

Tags: chromecast, receiver, caf

I am trying to customize buffering UI of CAF Receiver  (https://github.com/googlecast/BasicReceiverCAF).

Now I just have a black screen and a little progress bar on the screen left bottom corner, like from here https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/receiver#receiver-ui-buffer, but without a preview picture.

My question is, how to set this preview instead of the black background?

I tried:

```
 let playerElement = document.getElementById('player');
 playerElement.style
    .setProperty('--buffering-image', 'url("/img/megacast-placeholder.jpg")');
```

But this code affects on progress bar control, it replaces the ring on the image.Also, I tried other properties from here https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features

Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> --splash-image

is the property you should use. If it's for some reason not working with:

```
playerElement.style.setProperty('--splash-image', 'url("../img/megacast-placeholder.jpg")');
```

Try adding a separate style tag containing

```
#player {
  --splash-image: url("../img/megacast-placeholder.jpg"); 
}
```